# Get substring from string in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsrange

I have a string like this

```
<img alt=\"Marco Bueno\" src=\"http://u.goal.com/136600/136687_thumb.jpg\" style=\"float: left;margin:0 10px 10px 10px;\" title=\"Marco Bueno\" /><p style=\"float:left;\">Herrera is currently on national team duty representing the U-23 side that has already made history at the Toulon Tournament, while Bueno won the U-17 World Cup in 2011</p>
```

I want to get the "src"(http://u.goal.com/136600/136687_thumb.jpg) from this string. How can i get that in a dynamic way.

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to parse it, I guess ...

Comment: i am trying to parse it using asihttprequest library but not able to

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310773/nsstring-with-some-html-tags-how-can-i-search-for-img-tag-and-get-the-content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your url using like this...

```
NSRange divRange = [dateString rangeOfString:@"src=\"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (divRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSRange endDivRange;

        endDivRange.location = divRange.length + divRange.location;
        endDivRange.length   = [dateString length] - endDivRange.location;
        endDivRange = [dateString rangeOfString:@".jpg" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:endDivRange];

        if (endDivRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            divRange.location += divRange.length;
            divRange.length  = endDivRange.location - divRange.location + endDivRange.length;


            NSLog(@"BinarySecurityToken : %@",[dateString substringWithRange:divRange]);
        }
    }
```

**Output : 
http://u.goal.com/136600/136687_thumb.jpg**

Comment: also some responses in the xml dont have src(i.e no image)..so how can i handle that?

Comment: you can handle it in different way but i dont what kind of string

Answer (score 0):

you can get the `String` between two `String` like

```
-(NSString*)stringBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString)end {
    NSRange startRange = [self rangeOfString:start];
    if (startRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange targetRange;
        targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
        targetRange.length = [self length] - targetRange.location;   
        NSRange endRange = [self rangeOfString:end options:0 range:targetRange];
        if (endRange.location != NSNotFound) {
           targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
           return [self substringWithRange:targetRange];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
NSString *aString = @"<img alt=\"Marco Bueno\" src=\"http://u.goal.com/136600/136687_thumb.jpg\" style=\"float: left;margin:0 10px 10px 10px;\" title=\"Marco Bueno\" /><p style=\"float:left;\">Herrera is currently on national team duty representing the U-23 side that has already made history at the Toulon Tournament, while Bueno won the U-17 World Cup in 2011</p>";
NSRange r1 =[aString rangeOfString:@"src=\""];
NSRange r2 =[aString rangeOfString:@"\" style"];

NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);

NSString *subString = [aString substringWithRange:rSub];
```

Hope it helps you.