# How to extract image from a URL(e.g. www.google.com) in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I had an application in which i had some links for e.g.(google.com).i need to extract the image from that link as in Facebook share,(they are showing thumbnails)with the link before sharing,I need to know

```
NSString *url_ = @"foo://name.com:8080/12345;param?foo=1&baa=2#fragment";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_];

NSLog(@"scheme: %@", [url scheme]); 
NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]); 
NSLog(@"port: %@", [url port]);     
NSLog(@"path: %@", [url path]);     
NSLog(@"path components: %@", [url pathComponents]);        
NSLog(@"parameterString: %@", [url parameterString]);   
NSLog(@"query: %@", [url query]);       
NSLog(@"fragment: %@", [url fragment]);
```

like this in which way we can extract the image from that url(whatever it may be) Can anybody guide me on this?

Comment: You will need to grab the HTML from that URL and parse the HTML for images.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSScanner.

See in action on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310900/979990

You have to parse the entire html looking for the image you want to use as thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

well in facebook share, they kind of have screenshot of that webpage, not just images from that page.
you can use **UIWebView** to load that url and take screenshot of UIWebView.

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webView.bounds.size);
   [webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```